# Small app to extract data from Firebird DB

Tags: python, firebird

The company I work for has the following problem.
In certain cases, for a customs related issue, we need to print an additional document containing just some information from a precise invoice. Unfortunately our management software does not come with this feature.
Since I know PHP and JavaScript decently enough, being the company Web Master, I was wondering if it were possible to build a very small application that reads data from our management software DB and then it creates a pdf file.
I've talked to the people who made our management software and they told me that it is possible to connect to our DB through ODBC. I made a test with LibreOffice Base and it actually works. They used a Firebird database.
I did some research and I found out about Python, which seems quite easy to learn and very versatile.
And now, finally, it comes my question.
Do you think it's possible to extract  data from a Firebird DB using Python, without having installed a Firebird server? What would you do to create this very small application in a very little amount of time? My initial idea was to develop a Windows desktop application that every employee can run when he needs to print the aforementioned document.

Comment: Have you researched if there is a Python library to read that database? If there isn't, you can pretty much forget it – unless you are experienced with interpreting proprietary database file formats.

Comment: Yes, there are: FDB and firebirdsql are the two I tried a bit. But, from what I'm understanding, they both need a database server connected to the file I want to read. I was hoping for a serverless solution. Something like download the library, insert the path to the file and you get access to the information you want.

Comment: As fdb uses the firebird client library, you can also make it use Firebird embedded, but this is far too broad a question.

Comment: if u know JavaScript then maybe you know Node.JS ? Recently on StackOverflow many quesitons from people using Node.JS apps framework to work with firebird server. // Or you can just dump some tables using `fbexport` tool

Comment: `Something like download the library, insert the path` - that is called Firebird Server, Embedded Edition (in FB2/Windows) or Embedded Mode (in FB3 and/or Linux). HOWEVER if there is a Firebird server working with the database file - it would prohibit any other application to mess with it. So you would have to shutdown your "management software" and then shutdown the normal Firebird server to use Firebird Embedded in your app.

Comment: @Arioch'The thanks for the feedback. I will use FDB with FBE as you suggested. You have all been very helpful. Thank you very much again! :D

Comment: Usually people think about DB server installation having in mind some monsters like Oracle and Microsoft. Sure, they require GBs of disk space and installation process takes a lot of time. But FB in its own league regarding easiness of installation and maintenance. It take only few megabytes on disk and usually one can go with default options. And there is serverless embedded mode.

Comment: @matteobin that would be very weird decision. You already have Firebird Server running, as part of your "our management software". You should just connect to it and fetch the data. Otherwise you have to - you MUST! - shutdown that "our management software", then shutdown the Firebird server it used, and only then use FBE to read the database file. This looks much more fragile and much less practical! You already has Firebird server installed and running - just do what servers are designed for, USE it.

Comment: @Arioch'The I got your point. But I don't see how I could use the management app server, since it's embedded and I don't have access to the software code. Is it possible to tell FDB to use dlls inside a specific folder for the server?

Comment: There are too many uncertainties in the description of your specific situation, so an answer that would actually help you is pretty hard to give. Better hire an expert, or leave it to the people in your company who actually have knowledge of Firebird and your management software.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I see. Thank you very much for the feedback. It was mainly a curiosity, I thought it could have been an interesting small project.

Comment: And it could be, don't let this discourage you, but try to get buy-in and support within your company. Asking strangers on the internet how you could get something to work just isn't always the right way. If you had just asked how to use FDB with Firebird embedded, I might have posted an answer, but the implications of the background you've sketched makes me (and others as it seems) weary to provide an answer.